# Create a filter from a NN table

Tags: filter, symfony-1.4

My project deals with music.
i want to allow my users to filter the music's style then want to follow.

Here are my tables

```
sfGuardUser ------ n -------------------------- n --------- Style
                                 |
                             LikeStyle
```

My idea is to handle it with filters. It should displays all the existing styles by checkboxes, then the user can check theses box and it is saved in LikeStyle table.

I already use filters and I want to know if want I to do is possible.

Comment: If you want to save the info, it sounds more like a normal form than a formfilter. Why you think it's about filters? Please, give us more info about your problem

Comment: When the user check the style's boxes that he wants, he will listen only the musics he likes. So it looks like a filter for me. I may be wrong.

Comment: In fact, what I want to do is very simple. I want to replace the `select` list by `checkboxes` list.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should take a look to 'multiple' and 'expanded' options for sfWidgetFormChoice.class.php (at lib/vendor/symfony/lib/widget/) 
For checkboxes, both options should be set to true.

Comment: Fine, I think this is the good way to do it. But, what do you think about it ? I mean, when I'll have 50+ styles, or maybe more, what's the good way to make a friendly GUI ?

Comment: How are you printing the form? with "echo $form" or "echo $form['widget']"? However, the fastest way to customize the look and feel is to render that checkboxs one by one (manually), but keeping every checkbox name and value the same that "echo $form" does.

Comment: It was a question about ergonomy, as you gave me the technical solution, I can now think about how can I display my filter.

Comment: Maybe some javascript modal popup with all this options could be a good way to display the filters.